# Type mismatch during json deserialization

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to convert json `JsonData` containing time-series of parameters:

```
[
  [ timestamp1, [ [paramset1, ...], [paramset2, ...], ...] ],
  [ timestamp2, [ [paramset1, ...], [paramset2, ...], ...] ],
  ...
]
```

into structure ParamPoint

```js
export class ParamPoint{
    constructor(
        public tstamp: number,
        public paramSets: number[][]
    ){}
}
```

with a piece of code like this:

```js
let res = JsonData.map<ParamPoint>((p) => new ParamPoint(p[0], p[1]));
```

which result in an error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'number[][]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I would like to know what is that error mean and how should it be avoided.

Comment: Instead of: `let res = JsonData.map<ParamPoint>((p) => new ParamPoint(p[0], p[1]));` Can you do `let res = JsonData.map((p:any) => new ParamPoint(p[0], p[1]));` ?

Comment: @John Thanks, that line got rid of it. I'm just started to learn TypeScript and is it ... typescript-way of converting things?

Comment: I’ll post it as an answer as well.

Comment: I think you could still keep the ‘<ParamPoint>’, but it is important that ‘p’ is either typed correctly, or ‘any’ is used, if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
let res = JsonData.map<ParamPoint>((p) => new ParamPoint(p[0], p[1]));
```

Can you do

```
let res = JsonData.map((p:any) => new ParamPoint(p[0], p[1]));
```

Instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define type for your `jsonData` like for example this:

```
const jsonData: [number, number[][]][] = [
  [1, [[1, 3], [2, 9]]],
  [3, [[1, 7, 3], [2, 9]]],
]
```

else typescript will asume that everything in `jsonData` has type `number | number[][]` instead of `[number, number[][]]`

You can also try cast them like this

```
jsonData.map<ParamPoint>((p: [number, number[][]]) => new ParamPoint(p[0], p[1]))
```

or even better

```
jsonData.map<ParamPoint>(([a, b]: [number, number[][]]) => new ParamPoint(a, b))
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-77lczs)

Also, please don't call variables from a capital letter it's confusing reserve capital letter for class an types.

Comment: Good solution, but what if my json is not constant and come over http?

Comment: one of mapping solutions should work you can also use that `[number, number[][]]` as type signature for http request data like for example `this.http.get<[number, number[][]]>(...)`

Comment: Thanks. It is nice to know you can supply types to your requests, but I do prefer John's solution because it is concise and covers both local and remote json files.

Comment: his solution is basically mine but without correct types :P

Comment: I have to say I agree with @Xesenix. I prefer having strong/strict types, instead of using `any`, because using types are less prune to fail in the future.